# How to get all available install options for a port?

Tags: macos, opencv, macports

Basically I'd like to install opencv so that it makes use of tbb and boost with the complete source code. However I think I will need to know how to display all the available install options for a port. (Install options I mean "+sth" after a port name, is that how you call it?)

In my concrete example, my line starts like

```
sudo port install opencv +tbb +python27
```

but I am not sure how to get the dev and the boost options...

Any ideas how to display options? Or specifically for opencv?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I have found it:

Port install options are called **not options but variants**. And the command is:

```
port variants opencv
```

in my case.

For those who care -- although in the code of opencv I have fond USING_BOOST flags -- there is no extra variant for boost support (perhaps it is automatic?).
My complete install line is

```
sudo port install opencv +debug +python27 +qt4 +tbb
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer provided by Barnabas Szabolcs, I have also found the **info** command is helpful for finding more information about a port, including the available variants, but also provides other interesting bits of information, such as the software license, maintainers, etc.

```
port info opencv
```

The above command results in the following output (as of the current portfile):

```
opencv @3.0.0_1 (graphics, science)
Variants:             contrib, dc1394, debug, eigen, java, opencl, openni,
                      python27, python34, qt4, qt5, tbb, universal, vtk

Description:          OpenCV is a library that is mainly aimed at real time
                      computer vision. Some example areas would be
                      Human-Computer Interaction (HCI), Object Identification,
                      Segmentation and Recognition, Face Recognition, Gesture
                      Recognition, Motion Tracking, Ego Motion, Motion
                      Understanding, Structure From Motion (SFM), and Mobile
                      Robotics.
Homepage:             http://opencv.org

Extract Dependencies: unzip
Build Dependencies:   cmake, pkgconfig
Library Dependencies: zlib, bzip2, libpng, jpeg, jasper, tiff, ilmbase, openexr,
                      ffmpeg
Platforms:            darwin
License:              BSD
Maintainers:          stromnov@macports.org, openmaintainer@macports.org
```