# ffmpeg fails to build by MacPorts

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, macports

I've seen a many problems about this, but I didn't get a solution.

My OS is Yosemite and current OpenCV is 2.4.9

I'm trying to install OpenCV with TBB, but when I do it by `sudo port install opencv +debug +python27 +qt4 +tbb` ([through this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424305/how-to-get-all-available-install-options-for-a-port)):

> Rafaels-iMac:y3PQFyQhUG rafaelruizmunoz$ sudo port install opencv
>   +debug +python27 +qt4 +tbb
>
> Warning: The Xcode Command Line Tools don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
>
> Warning: Install them by running 'xcode-select --install'.
>
> Warning: The Xcode Command Line Tools don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
>
> Warning: Install them by running xcode-select --install'.
>
> --->  Computing dependencies for ffmpeg
>
> --->  Configuring ffmpeg Error: Failed to configure ffmpeg, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_multimedia_ffmpeg/ffmpeg/work/ffmpeg-2.6/config.log
>
> Error: org.macports.configure for port ffmpeg returned: configure failure: command execution failed Please see the log file for port ffmpeg for details:
>
> /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_multimedia_ffmpeg/ffmpeg/main.log
>
> Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
>
> Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade ffmpeg failed

And **there are not** any logs on those paths.

I've tried (support from SO and MacPorts).

- `port selfupdate`
- `port upgrade ffmpeg`
- `port clean x264`
- `port upgrade outdated`
- `port -f selfupdate`

but nothing happened.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT: Doing `xcode-select --install` doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: homebrew as a possible alternative? :)

Comment: Hello @rogerdpack. Thanks for your answer.

It was a clever solution, but didn't solve my problem. I installed ffmpeg via homebrew and updated everything. The same error happens.

Comment: Those warnings about xcode-select --install are a bit foreboding...did you restart your terminal? box?

Comment: I installed OpenCV on my Mac from source without problems. If you want to install OpenCV from source, you can follow the instructions [here](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/).

Comment: I don't understand the vote down....

Comment: Try to uninstall ffmpeg and than use `brew install opencv --with-ffpmeg`

Answer (score 0):

The code that produces this warning is at http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/base/src/port1.0/portutil.tcl?marks=3279-3289#L3266. On 10.10, it checks whether `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include` exists and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make` is executable. Since that's not the case on your system, the Command Line Tools have not been successfully installed.

After running `xcode-select --install`, a dialog box should pop up that allows you to click "Install" to install the Command Line Tools. See http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/ for screenshots.

Once you installed those, your build should work. If it doesn't, you'll have to upload the contents of the `main.log` for further diagnosis.